Wagtail: readonly list of models
Is it possible to create a readonly list of models with a custom queryset through a ModelViewSet in Wagtail admin?
I did not find a way in the documentation to specify this.
I could create a seperate SnippetViewSet:
class TodoListViewSet(SnippetViewSet):
    """
    Viewset for the to-do list.
    """

    model = Partner
    icon = "tasks"
    menu_label = _("To-do list")
    menu_name = "todo_list"
    name = "todo_list"

    list_display = [
        "name",
        "website",
        UpdatedAtColumn(),
    ]

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return Partner.objects.filter(
            partnerships__is_active=True,
            # Ignore levels -1 (text only) and 1 (text reference on partner page)
            partnerships__website_logo__gt=1,
            logo__isnull=True,
        ).order_by("name")

However I get an error that the model is already registered as a snippet (which is true).
In essence I want to have a seperate list of Partners in our system that match specific filters, next to the standard view.
